# FilePicker does not save files in my windows application

Tags: flutter, file, save, filepicker

I try to save an example file in my Flutter application for Windows based on the example provided by the pub.dev website, when I click on save the file it simply does not appear in the selected location.

https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker

Could you help me identify what mistake I'm making please?

```
    Future<void> _saveFile() async {
    String? outputFile = await FilePicker.platform.saveFile(
      dialogTitle: 'Please select an output file:',
      fileName: 'output-file.pdf',
    );

    if (outputFile == null) {
      // User canceled the picker
    }
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSG57.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znveW.png)

Comment: Does "output-file.pdf" actually exist? The concept is 1) application has an existing file (here "output-file.pdf") 2) application presents the user through "FilePicker" a dialog where to save that file to. You need to take care also from where the app is started, or provide an absolute path instead.